# Page specific CSS in Django with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

This is a question about what you guys feel is acceptable or the best way of handling a problem like I have right now.

I'm using a header in Django that I use everywhere, but on the landing page I want different styling on.

So instead of making two base templates with different headers and two sass files for them respectively. I just added 11 lines of javascript styling on the page in question. If they do not have javascript enabled then no issues will happen as the header normally works with pure css.

Is this bad practice? And is there better ways to do this that is not overly complicated?

Comment: You could add a `class` to header at landing page to use different `css` instead of using `javascript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add

```
{% block extra_css %}
    <link href="main_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
{% endblock %}
```

to your base.html header.

and in that landing page header:

```
{% block extra_css %}
    <link href="landing_page_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
{% endblock %}
```

this is a bit high level. you can add blocks which contain css classes that will be overriden once you override the block:

```
<div class="global_class {% block extra_csscls %}{% endblock %}">
```

and in landing page:

```
{% block extra_csscls %}landing_page_css_class{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hello again doniyor. I should have thought about blocks long ago. Duh, I feel stupid. Though I searched for answers on google, yet nobody really mentioned that. May be that I suck at googling.

Comment: @AndreasHalvorsenTollånes no problem, we all learn this way. django's template inheritance is really powerful if you use all what it offers